# Laravel carbon get sum of particular month values

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, php-carbon

I have a table with colums - start, stop,mechanic, labor_hrs. Basically it records the time of mechanic on a job.
I am trying to display the monthly total of hours of each mechanic in my template .

Controller:

```
public function index()
{

    $subith = Laborhrs::all()->where('mechanic','7');
    return view('reports.labour_monthly')->with('subith',$subith);
}
```

Template:

```
    @foreach($subith as $subith)
    <tr>
        <td>{{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($subith->stop)->format('M')}}</td>
        <td>{{$subith->labor_hrs}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

I get the results like this:

[image]

I need to get it like - total of sep for this employee and total of oct. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1: Group in query**

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $subiths = Laborhrs::selectRaw('MONTH(stop) as month, sum(labor_hrs) as sum')
        ->where('mechanic', 7)
        ->groupBy('month')
        ->orderByDesc('stop')
        ->get();

    return view('reports.labour_monthly', compact('subiths'));
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($subiths as $subith)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $subith->month, 1)) }}</td>
        <td>{{ $subith->sum }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

**Option 2: Group query result**

Do not use this option if you have a lot of data on each mechanic.

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $subiths = Laborhrs as sum')::where('mechanic', 7)
        ->orderByDesc('stop')
        ->get();

    $grouped = $subiths->groupBy(function($item){
       return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($item->stop)->format('F');
    });

    return view('reports.labour_monthly', compact('grouped'));
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($grouped as $month => $group)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $month }}</td>
        <td>{{ $group->sum('labor_hrs') }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: ->groupBy(DB::raw('MONTH(stop)'))   what does DB stands for?

Comment: @Thaha By default `groupBy()` accepts column names. Eloquent makes some preparings like adding table names to column names and etc. So, it brokes custom raw queries like that and you cant use `->groupBy('MONTH(stop)')` directly. You should wrap raw queries into `DB::raw()`.

Comment: Thanks. it throws as SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055  error

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'polygon07.laborhrs.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select *, sum(labor_hrs) as sum from `laborhrs` where `mechanic` = 7 group by MONTH(stop) order by `stop` desc)

Comment: @Thaha Are you using postgresql?

Comment: actually nope, its XAMPP, so its mySQL

Comment: why would you say - Do not use this option if you have a lot of data on each mechanic.

Comment: @Thaha The second method can run significantly longer than the first on a large amount of data. On a small amount of data (several hundreds of rows), the difference will not be significant.